# 7.9.1x doesn't start as a service - throws start limit hit error

Tags: sonarqube

I have followed the standard process of upgrading from 7.3 to 7.9.1 LTS. But couldn't get 7.9.1 running

- I have replicated wrapper.conf and sonar.properties
- Changed the version number from 7.3 to 7.9.1 in the sonarqube.service file
- removed zulu-8 and installed OpenJDK11
- Added the explicit path to java in wrapper.conf
- No logs get generated in the logs directory of SonarQube

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl status sonarqube.service
  sonarqube.service - SonarQube service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service; enabled; vendor preset
     Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Thu 2019-08-22 06:18:25 UTC; 2
    Process: 61751 ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.
    Process: 61685 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar
   Main PID: 3206 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

  Aug 22 06:18:25 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Service hold-off
  Aug 22 06:18:25 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Scheduled restart
  Aug 22 06:18:25 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: Stopped SonarQube service.
  Aug 22 06:18:25 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Start request rep
  Aug 22 06:18:25 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Failed with resul
  Aug 22 06:18:25 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: Failed to start SonarQube service.


  $ ls /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/logs/
  README.txt


  $ cat /etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service
  [Unit]
  Description=SonarQube service
  After=syslog.target network.target

  [Service]
  Type=forking

  ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
  ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop

  User=sonarqube
  Group=sonarqube
  Restart=always

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target

  $ cat /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/conf/wrapper.conf | grep java.command
  #wrapper.java.command=/path/to/my/jdk/bin/java
  #wrapper.java.command=java
  wrapper.java.command=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
  ```

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl status -l sonarqube.service
  ● sonarqube.service - SonarQube service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonarqube.service; enabled; vendor preset
     Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Fri 2019-08-23 13:42:58 UTC; 4
    Process: 2694 ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.s
    Process: 2598 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.

  Aug 23 13:42:58 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Service hold-off
  Aug 23 13:42:58 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Scheduled restart
  Aug 23 13:42:58 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: Stopped SonarQube service.
  Aug 23 13:42:58 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Start request rep
  Aug 23 13:42:58 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: sonarqube.service: Failed with resul
  Aug 23 13:42:58 sonarQubeServer systemd[1]: Failed to start SonarQube service.
  lines 1-12/12 (END)
  ```

Comment: Could you use `systemctl status -l sonarqube.service` so the status lines aren't tuncated?

Comment: added in the edit @mc1arke

Comment: Could you please paste the logs you get after running this `journalctl -u sonarqube.service`

Answer (score 4):

For me, I had to install Java.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Credits to http://www.continualintegration.com/miscellaneous-articles/how-do-you-troubleshoot-the-sonarqube-service-not-working-with-a-vendor-preset-disabled-error/

Comment: Thanks for posting here. This is working for me on Ubuntu 18.04